# Radius of convergence for $\ln(a+x)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

Since the radius of convergence $R$ for the Taylor series of $\ln(z)$ around $1$ is $1$, i.e.

$$ R\left\{\ln\left(1+z\right) = \sum \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k \right\} = 1 ,$$

does this mean that for

$$\ln\left(a+x\right) = \ln\left(a\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\right) = \ln\left(a\right) + \ln\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

the Taylor series converges for

$$-1 < \frac{x}{a} < 1$$

and hence for

$$-a < x < a ?$$

If so, this would seem to imply that if I take "large enough" $a$, then I can get convergent Taylor series expansion for $\ln(x)$ on

$$(0,2a)$$

covering a large range of positive reals?

If so, then if I needed to get convergence on $(b,c)$, is there a "good way" to choose $a$ so that the series converges fast at both ends"? (I suspect that the rate of converges for $x<a$ is different from that for $x>a$, so that choosing $a$ not simply as a mid point of $(0,c)$ might be better.)

Comment: The series will have slow convergence rate anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You can also use the fact that$$\log(z+a)=\log(a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{na^n}$$and that, assuming that $a>0$, the radius of convergence of this power series is (again) $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you also have a suggestion for choosing $a$ given a "target" convergence interval $(b,c)$? It's the last part of my opening question which I was finishing up when you already posted your reply. Thanks

Comment: Consider $\log\left((x-b)+\frac{c-b}2\right)$. It converges when $0<x-b<c-b$. But$$0<x-b<c-b\iff b<x<c.$$

Comment: Thank you. Is the rate of convergence at two ends of the interval the same? If not, would it be possible to get the same rate by choosing a different point of expansion with an overall larger interval of convergence but located in such a way that the rate is the same at both ends? Would this inevitably lead to deterioration of convergence at one of the ends?